# Entity Framework Core 3.0 Many-to-Many for the same table

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I am using ef core 3.0 code-first database. I have a table, `Status`, and I need to create a relationship to itself to list the possible "next status" `List<Status> SubsequentStatuses`. This is of course to systematically control the workflow of the object.

Using this at face value, it creates a one-to-many relationship and a new StatusId column in the table; however, I need to be able to set a status to be a "SubsequentStatus" to more than one Status.

For example, if there are 4 statuses:

- New
- In Work
- Complete
- Cancelled

I want to have the following

- New

  - Subsequent Statuses

    - In Work
    - Cancelled
- In Work

  - Subsequent Statuses

    - Complete
    - Cancelled
- Complete

  - None
- Cancelled

  - None

Notice that "Cancelled" is related to both "New" and "In Work"

Here are the classes and config that I have at this point:

```
public class EstimateStatus
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EstimateStatusRel> SubsequentStatuses { get; set; }
}

public class EstimateStatusRel
{
    public int EstimateStatusId { get; set; }
    public EstimateStatus EstimateStatus { get; set; }

    public int SubsequentStatusId { get; set; }
    public EstimateStatus SubsequentStatus { get; set; }
}

public class SapphireContext : DbContext
{    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<EstimateStatusRel>().HasKey(x => new { x.EstimateStatusId, x.SubsequentStatusId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<StatusRel>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Status)
            .WithMany(p => p.SubsequentStatuses)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.StatusId);
    }
}
```

The issue this is creating, is that when Entity Framework is building the migration, it errors out about the multiple cascading delete action, but when I add the `NoAction` modifier to the modelBuilder fluent API, it still does not clear the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up being because I didn't specify an `OnDelete` action

This is my final config:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<EstimateStatusRel>()
                .HasOne(pt => pt.Status)
                .WithMany(p => p.SubsequentStatus)
                .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.EstimateStatusId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

Answer (score -1):

For self-reference in one-to-many relationships, you could try the below code:

```
public class EstimateStatus
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    public EstimateStatus ParentStatuses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EstimateStatus> SubsequentStatuses { get; set; }
}

public class TestDbContext:DbContext
{
    public TestDbContext (DbContextOptions<TestDbContext> options):base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<EstimateStatus> EstimateStatuse { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<EstimateStatus>()
            .HasMany(e => e.SubsequentStatuses)
            .WithOne(s => s.ParentStatuses)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.ParentId);
    }
}
```

Comment: please review the question. The answer you provided is presenting a one-to-many relationship, I am looking for a many-to-many relationship